# HTML/MVC show only 3 lines... height must be auto

Tags: html, textarea

I am working on MVC application on IE 11 and I have a requirement to show only 3 lines even though the string can be very long. I tried different ways and started looking into textarea. In that also I tried various ways and I read blogs and posts and they al say use rows attribute. I gave rows=3 but I can see more than 3 lines. In one of the posts at SO they say try like below. I tried it but still if you see you can add some more text and you can see more lines.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea

How to really show only 3 lines. **I donot mind textarea or other controls**. I tried with span, p, and textarea.

In below image I need to show only 3 lines..

[image]

```
.threelinesTextArea
     {
        overflow:hidden; 
        resize:none; 
        border: none; 
        word-wrap:break-word; 
        white-space:normal;
     }

<textarea name="lblSellerNameValue" class="threelinesTextArea" rows="3" cols="40" maxlength="140">SellerName0 SellerLastName0, SellerName1 SellerLastName1, SellerName2 SellerLastName2, SellerName3 SellerLastName3, SellerName4 SellerLastName4 , SellerName0 SellerLastName0, SellerName1 SellerLastName1, SellerName2 SellerLastName2, SellerName3 SellerLastName3, SellerName4 SellerLastName4
 </textarea>
```

After using disabled.

[image]

**UPDATE - Solution**
I accepted Paul's answer below since that helped me to understand textarea and dig in more into it. I solved my issue like below using span eventhough textarea also worked perfectly fine.

```
<span style="display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word; white-space:normal; height:40px">
SellerLastName1, SellerName2 SellerLastName2, SellerName3 SellerLastName3, SellerName4 SellerLastName4 , SellerName0 SellerLastName0, SellerName1 SellerLastName1, SellerName2 SellerLastName2, SellerName3 SellerLastName3, SellerName4 SellerLastName4
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: As soon I posted it was down voted. Just curious to know who, how, and why...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you didn't post any code reproducing the problem.  The `rows` attribute works as expected in the link so it must be something specific to your css/layout.

Comment: @ Paul.. if you go to w3schools link which I posted in question and give resize="none" and overflow="hidden" in text area and just keep on typing something in text area you will see it will allow more than 3 lines.. then in such cases how we can say rows attribute will allow you to specify numbers of lines we want...

Comment: You original question said "show only three lines" and now you are saying "allow more than three lines", which is *completely* different.  `rows=` determines how high the text area is, it does not limit the amount of text you can type into it.  You can limit the amount of text using `maxlength=` but that is number of characters, not lines.

Comment: @ Paul.. my question is show only 3 lines. even I also feel that as suggested in some other accepted answers in SO rows will not limit the number of lines.. I got confirmation for your comment above...

Comment: Look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/VjKYEw Long text, but only displaying three lines.  What is the problem?

Comment: @ Paul.. thanks for sharing that link.. I appreciate it... the problem is that in textarea you put your cursor and press down key arrows on keyboard you will see some more lines. I will add image to my question. Please wait..

Comment: Why the heck this down voted again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any scrolling whatsoever, set it to `disabled`.

```css
textarea:disabled {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="3" cols="50" style="resize: none; overflow: hidden" disabled>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam luctus justo vitae elementum bibendum. Quisque tortor felis, laoreet id arcu quis, congue ultricies urna. Nulla efficitur, nulla vitae facilisis pulvinar, neque ante venenatis sem, in vehicula nisl mi sit amet metus. Sed sollicitudin felis nec pharetra eleifend. Proin eget dolor risus. Nam tempus diam maximus erat eleifend scelerisque. Ut ipsum massa, aliquet et erat eget, cursus imperdiet arcu. Donec feugiat eu magna sed imperdiet. Nunc congue pellentesque ipsum sit amet congue. Nunc mattis mauris odio. Cras consectetur est sagittis pretium luctus. Nullam at velit quis nibh vestibulum mattis. Donec aliquam ultricies gravida. Quisque dictum erat risus, eu tincidunt nulla bibendum quis. Donec viverra, eros vitae dignissim varius, mauris dolor sodales purus, tempor varius nisi enim vel risus.

Nam et tempor nisi. Suspendisse porta interdum elit non sagittis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc ultrices leo nec neque blandit scelerisque. Fusce eget mauris vulputate ipsum pellentesque facilisis. Nam id augue ut purus convallis faucibus id sed risus. Aliquam odio nulla, maximus eget condimentum sit amet, dictum ut ante.

Curabitur porttitor consequat tellus in dictum. Nulla efficitur tellus at arcu dictum maximus. Quisque quis sodales mauris, nec aliquet risus. Suspendisse mollis maximus consequat. Maecenas dapibus vitae lacus sed sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc ornare ex eget augue venenatis, quis congue est dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec leo tortor, pellentesque non velit a, molestie condimentum tortor. Pellentesque quis nisi nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque aliquet ante eget malesuada efficitur. Praesent id dolor id neque semper tincidunt. In non ligula id mi tincidunt vestibulum ut et orci.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Your HTML by itself only shows three rows and cannot scroll, there must be something about the structure of your page that is overriding it. You need to provide more context about what that textarea is contained in.   http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/BzLyXR